# How to export HTML file from R studio to SharePoint?

Tags: r, sharepoint, rstudio

I have created some graphs by using networkD3 package in R studio. A demo of these graphs is shown below:

[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUD7W.png)

The format of these files is either HTML. Now I am required to output these files to the SharePoint daily automatically. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you!

I try to use the code as below. But it does not work. Does anyone know how to do it? Thank you!

```
system("curl --ntlm --user useid:password --upload-file C:/Users/Demo/1.html https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/Test%20for%20upload/1.html")
```

Comment: I don’t know anything about Sharepoint, but you probably also need to transfer the folder/directory that contains all the additional files, no?

Comment: @CJYetman Thanks. Could you clarify it? I am now using one file to test the process. Thanks.

Comment: When you save as an HTML file, it creates more than just an HTML... it also creates a directory with additional files that are necessary for it to work (iirc).

Comment: Yes. But when I uploaded the HTML file only to the SharePoint, it also worked. Thanks!

Comment: But you said in the original question "But it does not work"? So what is the problem?

Comment: Thanks! I can manually upload the file to SharePoint. But I do not know how to upload it automatically by running R code. These files need to be updated daily. Hence, it is important for me to figure it out. Thank you! @CJYetman